# How to convert a Bitmap to an Image in Android

Tags: android-studio, android-bitmap

I’m relatively new in android programming and have a problem: I want to convert a Bitmap into an Image.

I couldn’t find a way to do this. Probably I’m searching wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to save the image in storage?

Answer (score 2):

Try This way

```
Drawable drawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), bitmap);

     //set imageview XML - call your image view
    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

References : Android Developers /[Bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

Drawable imageDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapImg);